# Meaning of $k$ in Sachs-Wolfe formula for angular power spectrum

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I've seen the formula for the angular power spectrum of the CMB written as

$$C_\ell = \frac2\pi \int\left|\Theta_\ell(k) \right|^2 k^2dk, $$

where $\Theta_\ell(k)$ is the temperature contrast at a given wavevector $k$ (the specific reference I'm using is the book "Primordial Cosmology" by Peter and Uzan (2009), pg. 313).  The expression for $\Theta_\ell(k)$ is derived from linear perturbation theory in a cosmological background, using *conformal time* $\eta$, as opposed to cosmic time $t$.  So it seems to me that $k$ in this formula is *not* the physical wavenumber, but rather the conformal wavenumber:
$$ k = ak_\text{phys},$$
where $a$ is the scale factor.  My issue is that if I'm using the conformal wavevector $k$ in the above formula for $C_\ell$, it seems to be non-gauge invariant.  I can make a transformation where I send $a\rightarrow a/\lambda$, $k\rightarrow k/\lambda$, $\eta\rightarrow \lambda \eta$, and $x^i\rightarrow \lambda x^i$.  This transformation doesn't seem to affect $\Theta_\ell(k)$, but does rescale $k$ so that the transformation of $C_\ell$ is 
$$C_\ell\rightarrow C_\ell/\lambda^3 $$
This does not seem like a very good feature for a physical observable. My question is how do I get a scaling invariant observable, and more generally what is the correct interpretation of $k$ in that formula?